# liveStreamingDetails for playlistItems YouTube Data API v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am looking for a way to detect if a video is a live stream. The YouTube Data API has a property `liveStreamingDetails` when using its [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint.

However this is not present when using the [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint.

Obviously I am not going to make another call (after `PlaylistItems.list`) just to get this property. Is there a way to find out what video from `PlaylistItems.list` is a live stream?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer to your question is negative:

As per the official specification, the [response returned](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#response) by the [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) API endpoint is a JSON object of which `items` property is an array of [PlaylistItems Resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource) objects:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": datetime,
    "channelId": string,
    "title": string,
    "description": string,
    "thumbnails": {
      (key): {
        "url": string,
        "width": unsigned integer,
        "height": unsigned integer
      }
    },
    "channelTitle": string,
    "videoOwnerChannelTitle": string,
    "videoOwnerChannelId": string,
    "playlistId": string,
    "position": unsigned integer,
    "resourceId": {
      "kind": string,
      "videoId": string,
    }
  },
  "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": string,
    "startAt": string,
    "endAt": string,
    "note": string,
    "videoPublishedAt": datetime
  },
  "status": {
    "privacyStatus": string
  }
}
```

This object contain only a limited amount of metadata info attached to the video items the `PlaylistItems.list` endpoint provides back.

Consequently, you have to acknowledge that, if needing the [`liveStreamingDetails`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails) property attached to videos returned by `PlaylistItems.list`, you have to request this info from the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint separately: query this latter endpoint by passing to its request parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) a comma-separated list made of the IDs of the videos of your interest (but no more than 50 of them).

Do note that each `Videos.list` endpoint call is very cheap: it has attached a [quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) of only one unit, irrespective of the number of video IDs passed on to it.

Comment: Doesnt quota depend on what fields you use in request?

Comment: @Toniq: no, quota is calculated per API endpoint call. It's good practice to ask from the API only the info of actual use by employing the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) parameter; however, this parameter has no influence on quota accounting -- it only reduces the network traffic and (possibly) the local processing of the respective API's JSON response.